# Strange pooling behavior on Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, pooling

This question is about very strange pooling behavior on Azure SQL database.

Here is the code to execute SQL commands:

```
async Task ExecuteSqlQuery(SqlCommand sqlCommand, Action<SqlDataReader> dataReaderHandler = null)
{
    try
    {
        // share execution between connections
        Func<SqlConnection, bool, Task> doQuery = async (connection, closeConnection) =>
        {
                sqlCommand.Connection = connection;

                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    await connection.OpenAsync();

                using (var dataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    dataReaderHandler?.Invoke(dataReader);
                }

                if (closeConnection)
                    connection.Close();
            };

            if (sqlCommand.Connection != null)
            {
                await doQuery(sqlCommand.Connection, false);
                sqlCommand.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = this.connectionSettings.BuildConnection())
                {
                    await doQuery(connection, true);
                    sqlCommand.Dispose();
                }
            }
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        throw;            
    }
}
```

This method works inside Azure Service Fabric which can run in two modes: locally (running under Visual Studio and connected to SQL Server 2016) and in Azure with Azure SQL. Connection strings in each case are:

```
Data Source=sqlLocal;Initial Catalog=SFDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Server=tcp:sqlazure.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=SFDB;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Max Pool Size=200;
```

Our Azure SQL Tier limited to 600 connections.

We using API to generate some data in database. This API calls 3 different SQL commands without sharing connection (`sqlCommand.Connection` is null so `closeConnection == true`)

Now the problem: on local SQL Server, everything works fine: we always have 45-46 connections in sleeping status, so pooling works fine, no problem, we can generate thousand of items in the database.

But in Azure DB, pooling works in a very different way. Looks like pooling doesn't work at all. Max Pooling totally ignored: very soon during objects generation the total number of connections reach limit of our tier (600) and we got the error:

> The session limit for the database is 600 and has been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance.

And SQL commands never re-use the existing connections, they are remaining in status sleeping for default .net sql client time (~4 minutes).

I have same behavior even when my local Service Fabric connected to Azure DB.

Question: why this happened and how to avoid?

PS: I'm using this query to get connection count (`sp_who` shows the same count):

```
SELECT c.session_id, s.status
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s ON c.session_id = s.session_id
WHERE c.session_id <> @@SPID
  AND s.status = 'sleeping'
```

Comment: How long do the queries run? The problem might not be different pooling behavior but a symptom that queries are taking longer for some reason. I would start by validating the execution plans are optimal.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know your scenario but I don't understand why you're trying to create your own pooling system. .NET / SqlConnection already have a internal pooling system. Doesn't it work for you?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: And why MultipleActiveResultSets is set to False?

Comment: @DanGuzman few ms, this is just INSERT of one record to DB

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino where did you see a custom pooling? I'm talking about OOB pooling.

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732740/active-azure-sql-connections-are-over-the-connection-pool-limit

Comment: @Alex yeah, I saw this question, but it's not really the same. I my case the key question is difference in behavior of same code on different SQLs.